# how to add ng-include into a div after click

Tags: javascript, html

Code:

```
  <head>
    <script>
    function getLink(link){
        var href = link.getAttribute("data-link");
        if(href == 'urlA'){
            $('#displayContent').attr('ng-include',"'abc/urlA.html'");
            }
        if(href == 'urlB'){
            $('#displayContent').attr('ng-include',"'abc/urlB.html'");
            }
        if(href == 'urlC'){
            $('#displayContent').attr('ng-include', "'abc/urlC.html'");
            }
        }
    </script>    
</head>
<body ng-controller="myController">
    <ul>
        <li data-link="urlA" onclick="getLink(this)">Include Url A</li>
        <li data-link="urlB" onclick="getLink(this)">Include Url B</li>
        <li data-link="urlC" onclick="getLink(this)">Include Url C</li> 
    </ul>
    <div id="displayContent"></div>
</body>
```

The div will become `<div id="displayContent" ng-include="'abc/urlA.html'></div>`
when i click the first list item, but the page doesn't include the "urlA.html".

Can anyone tell me the mistake?
btw, the page included another page when i write

`<div id="testing" ng-include="'abc/urlA'"></div>`

Comment: Take a look at http://embed.plnkr.co/M8N0Hk/

Answer (score 0):

try to change "'abc/urlA.html'" to "abc/urlA.html" same in B and C inside script tag

Comment: Tried but not working, i guess the single quote is required, thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

Within "onclick" callback you are outside of the "Angular Context".

You can:

- move from "onclick" to "ng-click"

  `<li data-link="urlA" ng-click="getLink(this)">Include Url A</li>`
- manually apply angular context by using $scope.$apply()

  ```
  function getLink(link){

      $scope.$apply(function () {

          var href = link.getAttribute("data-link");
          if(href == 'urlA'){
              $('#displayContent').attr('ng-include',"'abc/urlA.html'");
          }
          if(href == 'urlB'){
              $('#displayContent').attr('ng-include',"'abc/urlB.html'");
          }
          if(href == 'urlC'){
              $('#displayContent').attr('ng-include', "'abc/urlC.html'");
          }
      });
  }
  ```

Of course you need a Controller to manipulate the $scope.